# Running ASP.NET web application from command line

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have ASP.NET web application and would like to run it. The machine doesn't have Visual Studio installed on it. On my machine which has Visual Studio I was able to run the application using the steps mentioned in this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166319/Run-ASP-NET-Web-Application-from-Command-Prompt

However, the production box doesn't have WebDev.WebServer20.EXE. Obviously the exe file could be downloaded and then I could run the program, but on production box I can't do that.

Is there any other way to run ASP.NET program from command line? It is a simple program, I am not using any third-party dll files and there are no command line arguments.

Comment: Does it have `IIS` - after all, that exe is a "dev server" to test ASP.net web locally on a dev desktop that probably wouldn't have IIS by default (you can). If you want to go beyond that, [Project Katana](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/an-overview-of-project-katana) might interest you. Hth...

Comment: Or [IIS Express](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express)

Comment: Yes the machine I have has IIS. Could you tell me what to do next. Actually I am not a .NET developer so not familiar with all this. Any help would be great.

Comment: If you came here for the title - https://dailydotnettips.com/run-asp-net-web-application-from-command-prompt/ and https://forums.asp.net/t/1554426.aspx?Can+not+find+web+WebDev+WebServer+EXE+on+my+machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any other way to run ASP.NET program from command line? It is
>   a simple program, I am not using any third-party dll files and there
>   are no command line arguments.  I have has IIS. Could you tell me what
>   to do next. Actually I am not a .NET developer so not familiar with
>   all this. Any help would be great.

You are missing basic concepts.

You do not need to run ASP.Net Web Application like executable program. Production Sever doesn't need Visual Studio; it just requires IIS and targeted .Net Framework.

Since you have Visual Studio on your local machine, you can publish straight to production server. [Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis) is an example. - OR - Publish files to local folder and copy file to production folder.

Then create a site in IIS, and map Physical Path.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at hostable web core. For example http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2008/04/14/host-your-own-web-server-in-your-application-using-iis-7-0-hostable-web-core.aspx