# How to start Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager outside of Visual Studio 2022

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I created "Asp.NET Core 6.0 with Angular" app in VS 2022 via a VS template.
It worked just fine and I can start it from VS with one click.
It then opens 2 command line windows and a browser.

In one window it starts ASP.NET app and a proxy and in another it starts Angular app and you can see it all work in the browser.

I want to start the whole thing from outside of VS.

To be clear I am **not** looking to set up another web server like IIS or nginx I want to run this with tools already available with my visual studio installation.

I can start the ASP.NET part by simply running the exe in the bin folder.

I can also run the Angular part of it with ng serve.

The missing part is the proxy. I can see it getting started in the purple command window when I run the whole thing from VS.

How do I run it (Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager) outside of VS?

Comment: Have you tried copying it to a web server? Then just hitting the server with your browser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running ASP.NET web application from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597461/running-asp-net-web-application-from-command-line)

Comment: No. First of all I do not want to configure it under yet another web server like IIS or nginx (I have a separate question for that). I want to run it as is with what I already have installed as part of visual studio 2022.